# Stack Overflow logo being truncated at the bottom on the Data Explorer

Tags: support, design, data-explorer, firefox

On selecting Stack Overflow on the Data Explorer, the logo is getting truncated at the bottom:

> [image: logo]

And the same for other sites logo:

> [image: meta]

It's a minor issue and need some CSS changes.

I am using:

- Windows 7
- Firefox 26
- Resolution 1280 * 1024

Comment: [`status-nonrepro`](http://i.imgur.com/9fSleRI.png) here.

Comment: Yup, confirmed. Firefox only though. Only when zoomed.

Answer (score 1):

It's a rather nasty Firefox only "feature" that performs auto zoom based on your screen resolution.

You have to turn it off as explained [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/963773):

> - Type *about:config* into the Firefox address bar and tap on the Enter key.
> - If the warning *This might void your warranty* appears, click *I'll be careful, I promise*.
> - Search for `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx`
> - Double-click on `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` to modify its value. The default is -1.0 in Firefox 22 and above. Change it to 1.0 to make it work like in previous Firefox versions.

Now click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to reset your zoom and you're all done. Nothing will be cut off.

Worked for me like a charm. :)

Comment: its producing for me on 100% zoom view.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed I know, did you cancel that new feature as described in the quoted article?

Comment: My point is, we cannot ask each user to turn off this feature. We need to fix it in any case.

Comment: Valid point, but not sure site should adjust to horrible browser features. Proper course of action should be to convince Firefox to cancel this silly thing or at least disable it by default.

Answer (score 0):

The current CSS is:

```
#aboutSite img.site {
    width: 140px;
}
```

Change it to:

```
#aboutSite img.site {
    width: 142px;
}
```

> [image: changed logo]